# Delete Non numeric row from a csv

Tags: bash, sed, awk, tr

I have used `sed` to allow only numeric and csv format ,I have used `sed '/[^0-9, -, .]/d'` as regex. It has still `"_","1-0","1-1"` character as o/p which worries me.

```
sed 's/'"$(printf '\015')"'//g' ./abc.CSV | sed '/[^0-9, -, .]/d' 
1,090216002122,128,126,134,124,-0,00,220,28,292688,077,040911,0858,0159
1,090216002123,128,126,134,124, 000,00,_220,28,292688,077,040911,0858,0159
1,090216002125,128,126,134,124, 000,00,220,28,292688,077,040911,0858,170
1,090216002126,128,126,134,124, 000,-.00,220,28,292688,077,040911,0858,0159
1,090216002130,128,126,134,124, 000,00,220,28,292688,077,040911,0858,   
1,090216002134,128,126,134,124, 000,00,220,28,,077,040911,0858,0159
1,090216002135,128,126,134,124, 000,00,220,28,077,040911,0858,0159
11,090216002137,128,126,134,124, 000,00,220,28,292688,077,040911,0858,0159
1-1,090216002137,128,126,134,124, 000,00,220,28,292688,077,040911,0858,0159
1,000000000000,000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,040216002137,128,126,134,124, 000,00,220,28,292688,077,040911,0858,0159
1,090216002137,128,126,134,124, 000,00,220,28,292688,077,040911,0858,0-1
```

I have tried with `($9 ~ /^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$/ )` doesnt seems to work with space number. I have also tried with

What is the best way to parse only numeric from a csv file? Thanks.

Comment: Show original csv and desired csv please. Also do you want to delete invalid lines or just remove invalid data inline ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your command:

```
sed '/[^0-9, -, .]/d'
```

#### What this actually does:

It deletes any lines that have any characters *besides* the following:

- a number (0-9)
- a comma
- any character from a space to a comma—which includes underscores, by the way, as well as hyphens
- a period.

So any line that has *any character* other than these, gets deleted.

#### What you think this does:

I'm not sure.